# В массиве строк выставить абзацы

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, char

Есть следующий массив:

```
char* ps[] = {"abcdefg", "hijklmn"};
```

Надо в каждой строке раз в два символа поставить абзацы.

Пробовал так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ps); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            ps[i][2 * j] = "\n";
        }
    }
    cout << ps[n] << endl;
```

Но ругается. Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: Не писать в память которую вы не выделяете?

Comment: Не понимаю. Можете подробнее?

Comment: Как минимум это `const char* ps[]`, и писать в него нельзя. Так что нужен новый массив, в который и переносить ваши символы, перемежая их `\n`.

Comment: Нет пока можно и не константными : `char ps[][100] = {"abcdefg", "hijklmn"};` @Harry

Comment: @AlexGlebe Можно. Но автор вопроса этого не делал. В условии четко сказано - **есть** (уже есть, задан) вот такой массив...

Comment: Поставить абзацы это вписать во внутрь строк UNIX перенос строк? А как-же табуляция для абзаца? А почему вы меняете буквы , пытаясь что-то добавить? Не компилируется, нет переменной `n`.